# How to submit form including image on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this HTML:

```
<form id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="design_title" class="form-label">Ttile of the design</label>
                <input type="text" name="design" class="form-control" id="design_title">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="design" class="form-label">Upload a new design</label>
                <input type="file" name="design" class="form-control" id="design">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <label for="fontsize" class="form-label">Enter the font size</label>
                <input type="number" name="design_font_size" class="form-control" id="fontsize">
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <label for="position_x" class="form-label">Position X</label>
                <input type="number" name="design_x" class="form-control" id="position_x">
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <label for="position_y" class="form-label">Position Y</label>
                <input type="number" name="design_y" class="form-control" id="position_y">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label class="form-label" for="domain">Choose a domain</label>
        <select name="domain" id="domain" class="form-control" data-form="design_output">
            <option value="">--Choose--</option>
            <?php 
            $get_domain = mysqli_query( $mysqli, "SELECT * FROM eg_domains");
            if( mysqli_num_rows( $get_domain ) > 0 ) {
                while( $get_result = mysqli_fetch_array( $get_domain, MYSQLI_ASSOC ) ) {
                    $domain_name = $get_result['domain_name'];
                    $company = $get_result['company_name'];
                    $domain_id = $get_result['domain_id'];
                    echo "<option value='$domain_id'>$domain_name ($company)</option>";
                }
            }
            ?>
        </select>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary ajax-btn output-desing" data-form="output_design">Output Design</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success ajax-btn">Save Design</button>
    <div class="mt-3">
        <div class="result"></div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Now, on **Output Design** button click I want to get all the data including image.

**So, I am doing this in JQuery/Ajax:**

```
$(document).on("click", ".output-desing", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var form = document.querySelector(".output-desing");
    var form_name = form.dataset.form;
    var data = $("#form").serialize() + "&form=" + form_name;
    // var data = '1';
    console.log(data);

    $.ajax({
        dataType: "html",
        type: "GET",
        url: 'helper/process.php',
        data: data,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        beforeSend: function () {
            $(".output-design").val("Please wait...");
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $(".output-design").html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

But I can get only form data not image data.

How can I get all the data including image data on that button click?

Comment: [serialize](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/#serialize) "_creates a text string in standard URL-encoded notation_", and as you already know, you need multipart/form-data instead.

Answer (score 0):

Anyways, I fix it this way:

```
var form = document.querySelector(".output-desing");
var form_name = form.dataset.form;
var data = new FormData(document.getElementById("form"));
data.append('form', form_name);
```